# Basics : Sending a signal from an external hardware connected via USB port to android phone to make custom app do stuff

Tags: android

I just need some initial directions as I am new when it comes to electronic hardware and android phone/app interaction. I am comfortable in both domains within their boundaries.

I have a black box electronic circuit. To simplify things lets assume all it does is, send binary 1 or 0 i.e. electric On or Off pulse. I need to connect this circuit to the android phone via USB(either Host/accessory mode) and want my android app to react to this pulse.

If possible - start the app when the phone receives 1/ON signal 
              OR display an "Switched ON" dialog message while the app is running in background as a service

Please dont worry too much about the electronics part. I'm aware that this is a software/programming forum.

e.g. black box : a electronic thermometer that sends a pulse/1/On signal if the temperature goes to 100 degrees Centigrade OR anything similar that's on a simple circuit board(no processor or programming language/architecture dependent) and could trigger a signal that could be sent to the android phone to inform my app that the event occurred.

another even simpler example, an earphone that has a connect/disconnect call button connected to audio jack of the android phone. i just need to replicate this functionality. instead or ear phone, my electronic BB and instead of phone call program, a custom android app.

Links, DIY projects, Tuts anything will be really helpful

Comment: A big, wide question.  Too wide to get a single answer.  Sounds interesting though, good luck.  Start here, then come back for more ;)  http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html

Comment: BTW, XDA Devs would be a great place to try as well.

Comment: Can you give more information about `black box`?

Comment: updated the question for further clarity

Comment: I'm searching for similar question with a slight difference - reading data send via USB on a Mac / RasPi device...

Answer (score 4):

This is a big open question. I'm guessing what you are asking for is a "real-world <=> Android" USB interface. This requires some hardware and some software. You may want to have a look here:

http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-sensors/yocto-knob

http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/sample-applications-for-android

You may also want to have a look at the competition

www.phidgets.com

Be aware that making a USB device working with an Android device is not as straight forward as it sounds: you will need a Android device able to work in host mode, the Android image used in the device must support USB devices and you may have a power problem if the device is supposed to be powered from the USB port you are planning to use.

The experience shows that the cheapest an Android device is, the more unlikely it will work with exotic USB devices.